# Paypal Express Checkout Timeout

Tags: php, paypal

Integrated with Paypal Express Checkout, the PHP SDK, tested in sandbox and worked fine, tested on live, worked fine.

Just got some notifications that payments were failing. As far as I was concerned things were working fine, nothing has changed, but now its stopped working :(

When I try it out I get a fatal error, and debugging returns:

```
[url:PPConnectionException:private] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/
[message:protected] => connect() timed out!
```

It is failing on SetExpressCheckout(), I have checked the API password and signature, which haven't changed since it was working. Nor has the code itself.

Bit annoyed as its NYE, my other halves birthday, and only a week ago we had our second child, so I am enjoying paternity leave and now have to deal with this :( I am stumped, any ideas?

Comment: Congrats on the second wee one! Well, can you provide a little more info? Off the top of my head you don't have any error handling for timeouts-- affording you the ability to retry if such happens, which CAN HAPPEN, especially during high volume shopping seasons--read, now! Those are rare, however. What do you have going on in IPN land?

Comment: thanks @DudeSolutions :) IPN turned on, nothing special other than that. Its not even getting to paypal to be able to make the payment in the first place though. Its failing on the SetExpressCheckout function which sets up the transaction. Not sure what other info reuired, just using standard SDK functions for express checkout which was working fine, now isnt :(

Comment: Are you still having issues? It's more likely to be a network-level timeout. If you're still having issues, let me know.

Comment: so after all that, it turned out that paypal had blocked the shared server i was on, the short of it being my hosts moved me to another server and it was fine... missions!!